# How many ways we can partition a multiset, where each part/segment in the partition has distinct elements?

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics, recursion, permutations

We define the set S as $\{(s_1, f_1), (s_2, f_2), ..., (s_i, f_i)\}$, where each $f_i$ is the frequency that $s_i$ is repeated in the multiset T. How many ways can we partition the multiset T into different partitions, where each partition includes distinct part/segments? A distinct part/segment includes distinct $s_i$s.

For example, given $S = \{(s_1, 1), (s_2, 2), (s_3, 1)\}$ results in the multiset $T = \{s_1, s_2, s_2, s_3\}$, where s1 is repeated once, s2 is repeated twice, and s3 repeated once in the multiset. Now, we can partition the multiset into six different partitions, where each partition includes distinct parts/segments as follows:

1:$\{\{s_1,s_2\},\{s_2,s_3\}\}$

2:$\{\{s_1,s_2,s_3\},\{s_2\}\}$

3:$\{\{s_1,s_2\},\{s_2\},\{s_3\}\}$

4:$\{\{s_1\},\{s_2\},\{s_2,s_3\}\}$

5:$\{\{s_1,s_3\},\{s_2\}, \{s_2\}\}$

6:$\{\{s_1\},\{s_2\},\{s_2\},\{s_3\}\}$

- Note that the order of elements in each segment does not matter, e.g., $\{s_1, s_2\} = \{s_2, s_1\}$
- Note that each subset has different/distinct elements.

Now, I am looking for **a formula** that counts the number of partitions of the set T, where $S = \{(s_1, f_1), (s_2, f_2), ..., (s_i, f_i)\}$. I am curious to know if it is possible to compute it in terms of the number of elements in the set S and the corresponding frequencies.

Comment: In your example, you are not considering $\{\{s_1, s_2, s_2\}, \{s_3\}\}$ as a partition (and many other ones). I don't see the reason why mentioned in your explaination. Could you either elaborate on the types of partition you want to compute? (this is perhaps what you are calling "each segment has different elements", but it is unclear)

Comment: Yes. Each segment has "distinct" elements. So, in your example, s2 has repeated twice, which is invalid.

Comment: However, in your example, the 5th one is $\{\{s_1, s_3\}, \{s_2, s_2\}\}$… In this one, $s_2$ is also repeated twice in a subset.

Comment: It means that the distinct segment {s2} has been repeated twice. The distinct segments can be repeated but the elements in the segment cannot.

Comment: Honestly, this is confusing. I suggest you use a notation with curly brackets, similarly to what I wrote, as to remove confusion between $\{\{s_1, s_3\}, \{s_2, s_2\}\}$ and $\{\{s_1, s_3\}, \{s_2\}, \{s_2\}\}$. Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: I edited your post to remove your notation with the number of occurrences, which is unconventionnal. Revert the modification if you think it is irrelevant.

Comment: "each si is the frequency that it is repeated" - what does "it" refer to in this phrase?  Are you sure $s_i$ is the frequency?  What does "each partition includes distinct part/segments" mean?  Can you elaborate in a bit more detail?  Can you specify that with mathematics?  What is the context in which you encountered this question or the motivation for asking?  Please [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4622246/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/157017/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.

Comment: @D.W: I posted the same question here as someone answers the computer science point of view, such as a recursive approach. The answer is given in math.stackexchange.com is purely in mathematics.